# Why do I keep getting this error message: "git was not detected on system path"

Tags: error, path, git

I'm not familiar at all with coding or using rstudio since this is the first semester im taking it. Basically everything was working fine, but when i updated to mojave, this error started popping up when i would try to create a new project in rstudio with git. I then realized i didnt have git intalled anymore so I installed git again ( git version 2.19.0) and followed steps from http://happygitwithr.com/  to connect to github and everything i initially did to work in rstudio but for some reason it didn't work. I then installed xcode (xcode-select --install), but that still didn't work. I think my path for git is right too (/usr/bin/git) so i have no idea what to do.

Edit: I've been looking through different questions on here and trying to find a solution but haven't been able to find anything

Comment: Which other answers did you try, what was the result?

Comment: The oath /usr/bin/git is wrong if you installed a non aplle supplied got how did you install got?